# How to properly store data in a C# array

Tags: c#, arrays

So I want to store the following data to `users = new DB[10];`

```
Console.WriteLine("=====REGISTER=====");
Console.Write("What is your name? ");
name = (Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("How old are you? ");
age = (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
Console.Write("What is your gender? M for Male, F for Female");
gender = (Console.ReadLine());
```

Currently I have this and the problem is it only saves the first set of data I input.

```
while (users[i] != null)
{
    i++;
}
users[i] = new DB(name);
users[i].SaveData(name, age, gender);
```

where

```
public void SaveData(string a, int b, string c)
{
    name = a;
    age = b;
    gender = c;
}
```

Comment: You could use `List<>` which would make dynamic adding easier as you do not need to set a fixed size (simply `users = new List<DB>()];` and `users.Add(new DB { ... })`). Back to your array case, do you set `i = 0` before the loop?

Comment: Yes, sorry I left it out. It happens at the start of the class. Our professor hasn't taught `List<>` yet and we have to deal with it the long way.

Comment: That `while (users[i] != null)` is pretty dangerous, you'll more likely than not hit an `IndexOutOfRangeException` with that. You should use something like `for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)` instead. But that's a minor issue that's part of problematic code...

Comment: Alright! Will revise with the for loop instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using For loop (as suggested by AlphaDelta in the comments) and your specific situation could be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
{
    if (users[i] == null) 
    {
        users[i] = new DB(name);
        users[i].SaveData(name, age, gender);
        break;
    }
}
```

This basically iterates your users array looking for the next `null`, and if found, it will save a user there, `break` means it stops the loop immediately.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to input data in for loop, like that:

```
       Console.WriteLine ("=====REGISTER=====");

        var users = new DB[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
        {
            //input data
            Console.Write ("What is your name? ");
            name = (Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.Write ("How old are you? ");
            age = (int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ()));
            Console.Write ("What is your gender? M for Male, F for Female");
            gender = (Console.ReadLine ());
            // store data
            users[i] = new DB (name);
            users[i].SaveData (name, age, gender);
        }
```

Update 1:

```
        static DB[] users = new DB[10];

        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            //user 1
            Registration ();
            //user 2
            Registration ();

        }

        private static void Registration ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("=====REGISTER=====");
            Console.Write ("What is your name? ");
            name = (Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.Write ("How old are you? ");
            age = (int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ()));
            Console.Write ("What is your gender? M for Male, F for Female");
            gender = (Console.ReadLine ());

            int i = 0;
            while (users.Length > i && users[i] != null)
            {
                i++;
            }
            if (users.Length > i)
             {
               users[i] = new DB ();
               users[i].SaveData (name, age, gender);
             }
        }
```

Comment: That works but then the entire registration process loops. What if I only wanted it to save one user at a time? Let's say every time I call `Registration()` from main?

Comment: @polors2 have a look at update 1 code, maybe that is your need